# plugin error missing when opening excel file with VB script

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I try to write a piece of code with VB script to open an excel file, take a print screen and send it by email.

This is on my professional laptop and I have several plugin installed on excel.
The excel file in question has a macro inside which run on each opening but does nothing fancy (mostly formatting data).

When I open the workbook normally, everything works fine.
When I launch the VB script, I have a error with a missing xla file (refer to file attached)

The code is quite simple:

```
 Dim Xl 'as Excel.Application\par
 Dim wk 'as Excel.workbook\par
 set Xl = createobject("Excel.application")
 Xl.Visible = True
 Xl.enableevents = True
 set Wk = Xl.workbooks.open("XXX")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to open workbook via shell:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oExcelApp, oWorkbook

CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Test\Test.xlsm"
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    WScript.Sleep 5
Loop While Err
On Error Goto 0
Set oWorkbook = oExcelApp.Workbooks("Test.xlsm")
oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = Now()
```

Comment: THank you, the issue is still the same. Apparently it's well know that the addin are not loaded in the same time when launched with VBS and I don't have a workaround as it's a company laptop. My only solution is to disable the addin.